# why this regular does not Match the html using python

Tags: python, regex

the html is :

```
<div style="background-color:#A7A7A7;text-align:center;">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;">{{rk_user.name}}のｽﾃｰﾀｽ</span>
</div>
```

my Regular is :

```
a = r'''
<div style="background-color:#([a-z0-9]+);text-align:center;">
\s*<span style="color:#(.+?);">(.+)</span>
</div>
'''
```

but this Regular does not Match the html ,

so what is wrong  ?

thanks

Comment: What's wrong is that you're using regex to parse HTML.

Comment: `#([a-z0-9]+)` is not matching upper-case characters would be my guess.

Comment: It has been pointed out in dozens of other questions that a regex is not a suitable tool for parsing HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the regex case insensitive because the color is #A7A7A7 and you're matching #a7a7a7.

You can try it on many sites as: http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 2):

## Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. Please!

Use [an HTML parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)!

---

Why not use regex, you ask?

- [Regular expression to match closing HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524364/regular-expression-to-match-closing-html-tags)
- [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege)
- [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)
- [Can regular expressions be used to match nested patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)
- [How do HTML parses work if they're not using regexp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm)
- And the ever-famous [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I would like to point out that BeautifulSoup is basically a bunch of regular expressions. This answer is still correct, but it adds an interesting perspective.

Comment: That's an extreme simplification. Many parsers for many languages can make use of regular expressions, but that's very different from a parser that consists of a big pile of regex. It is impossible to implement an HTML (or XML, for that matter) parser strictly using regular expressions, because HTML and XML are context-free, not regular, languages. Have you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400623/if-youre-not-supposed-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-then-how-are-htm)?

Comment: fair enough, 'basically a bunch' was dramatic. There is of course a great deal more to BeautifulSoup, and your answer to the question on this page shows in depth how regular expressions on their own are not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you have a case-sensitivity problem in the color.  Plus, you might want to meditate on BoltClock's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Like @BoltClock mentions, it is not recommended to use regex like this. If not now, sometime down the line you will regret it. There are lots of corner cases which will make the regex complex and also plain useless at times.

Anyway, at a cursory glance, for background-color you have used `[a-z0-9]` that will only match lower case. But the sample has uppercase. You may want to have upper case as well `[a-zA-Z0-9]` For the other colors also, why don't you use the same? Why a `(.+?)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what many other people are saying, you may want to use the `re.UNICODE` flag, since it looks like you have some Japanese characters in there.