# Reformatting XML file to text file without tags

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have a text file as:-

```
<author>Frank Drewes</author>
<author>Johanna H&ouml;gberg</author>
<author>Andreas Maletti</author>
<title>MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.</title>
<pages>165-189</pages>
<year>2011</year>
<volume>48</volume>
</article>
```

I need to remove all the angular brackets in it as:-  and  and provide the name inside the angular bracket withour brackets along with a hyphen as;-

```
author-Frank Drewes
author-Johanna H&ouml;gberg
author-Andreas Maletti
title-MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.
pages-165-189
year-2011
volume-48
```

Comment: What should be the output in the case of nested tags?

Comment: regex will only bring you more problems and head explosion. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3100115)

Comment: [A related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3524392/736937) worth reviewing.

Answer (score 2):

Instead diving into the wonderful world of regular expressions, I would use a specific tool - a parser, like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

Working example:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = u"""
<article>
  <author>Frank Drewes</author>
  <author>Johanna H&ouml;gberg</author>
  <author>Andreas Maletti</author>
  <title>MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.</title>
  <pages>165-189</pages>
  <year>2011</year>
  <volume>48</volume>
</article>
"""

root = fromstring(data)

for element in root.iterchildren():
    print '%s-%s' % (element.tag, element.text_content())
```

Prints:

```
author-Frank Drewes
author-Johanna Högberg
author-Andreas Maletti
title-MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.
pages-165-189
year-2011
volume-48
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, please, please go with alexce's approach if at all possible.  (And if not, try to find a way to make it possible -- [see this answer for rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524364/regular-expression-to-match-closing-html-tags/3524392#3524392)).  I'm just throwing this here for variety.

Using [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match), named groups and backreferences.

```
import re

input_lines = '''<author>Frank Drewes</author>
<author>Johanna H&ouml;gberg</author>
<author>Andreas Maletti</author>
<title>MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.</title>
<pages>165-189</pages>
<year>2011</year>
<volume>48</volume>'''.splitlines()

out_lines = []
for line in input_lines:
    mat = re.match(r'<(?P<tag>[^>]+)>([^>]*)</(?P=tag)>', line)
    if mat: out_lines.append("%s-%s" % mat.groups())

print '\n'.join(out_lines)
```

Output:

```
author-Frank Drewes
author-Johanna Högberg
author-Andreas Maletti
title-MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.
pages-165-189
year-2011
volume-48
```

Comment: how can i write this from opening a file rather than `input_lines`? should i specify, `with open('f.txt','r') as input_lines`?

Comment: Sure, that would work -- or what I'd probably do for clarity is `with open('f.txt', 'r') as input_file:` then replace `for line in input_lines:` to `for line in input_file:` -- (but please, consider alexce's approach) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below `re.sub` command but it won't deal with the nested tags.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''<author>Frank Drewes</author>
<author>Johanna H&ouml;gberg</author>
<author>Andreas Maletti</author>
<title>MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.</title>
<pages>165-189</pages>
<year>2011</year>
<volume>48</volume>
</article>'''
>>> m = re.sub(r'<(\w+)\b[^>]*>([^<]*)</\1>', r'\1-\2', s)
>>> print(re.sub(r'<[^<>]*>', '', m))
author-Frank Drewes
author-Johanna H&ouml;gberg
author-Andreas Maletti
title-MAT learners for tree series: an abstract data type and two realizations.
pages-165-189
year-2011
volume-48
```